# How to setup Apache 2.2 (prefork) with mod_fcgid to test a C++ application?

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have written my first fastcgi application (C/C++), and I need to test it to ensure that it is behaving the way I expect it to.

I have searched for examples on setting up Apache 2.2. with mod_fcgid, but all of teh tutorials etc I have seen, relate to PHP, Python, Perl etc.

Is anyone aware of a resource that shows how I may setup Apache to use mod_fcgid (NOT mod_fastcgi) to test my binary?

If no online resource is available (I'd be surprised), then could someone please point out the steps required to do the testing?

Answer (score 1):

The mod_fcgid examples are actually pretty comprehensive wrt the hairy apache configuration side:

http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples